Spring Cache: CachePut does not call method to read data for update
My application was upgraded from Spring Boot 1.2.6 to 3.2.3.
It uses Spring Cache and Ehcache.
Now in Spring Boot 3 only one cache is loaded when calling @CachePut annotated method although cache is cleared before.
@CachePut(value = CacheDefinitions.USERS)
@Override
public Map<String, User> refreshUsers() {
    try {
        dataFileStore.clearCache(CacheDefinitions.USERS);
        return mappingDataRepository.getUsers().get(); <--- getUsers() is not called
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

This one is called:
@CachePut(value = CacheDefinitions.HANDLERLISTMAP)
@Override
public Map<String, ListAccessLists> refreshHanderListMap(){
    dataFileStore.clearCache(CacheDefinitions.HANDLERLISTMAP);
    return proxy.getHandlerListMap(); <-- this one is called
}

This one also is not called:
@CachePut(value = CacheDefinitions.HANDLERBETRIEBLISTMAP)
@Override
public Map<String, List<String>> refreshHandlerBetriebListMap() {
    try {
        dataFileStore.clearCache(CacheDefinitions.HANDLERBETRIEBLISTMAP);
        return mappingDataRepository.getHandlerBetriebListMap().get(); <-- not called
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

3rd example not called:
@CachePut(value = CacheDefinitions.HANDLERLISTMAP)
@Override
public Map<String, ListAccessLists> refreshHanderListMap(){
    dataFileStore.clearCache(CacheDefinitions.HANDLERLISTMAP);
    return proxy.getHandlerListMap(); <-- not called
}

Why ListHandlerMap is refreshed, but not Users, HandlerBetriebslistMap and HandlerListMap? I see no difference between them.

I don't get how this should have worked? The method would only be called if the cache was empty in the first place. So when being called the cache is empty but you are clearing it anyway.

I do log cache clearing and it is called, but the next step is an async call to a data load method and this async method is not called anymore. Worked at Spring Boot 1.2.6.

The fact that it worked doesn't mean it was supposed to work. Also what you state in your comment is also different from what you state in your question. As stated if there is a cache an dit is filled the method will not be called as there is already something in the cache. Also you are upgrading about 14 versions in one go, you did read all the changes and update documents didn't you?

I had to wait several years to be able to upgrade because my customer did not want to pay it. I upgraded this app with a colleague who did read all the changes, but unfortunately he left the company this year. With SB 1.2.6 I did not have to clear cache before, I added this statement in this SB version since I figured that there still is something in the cache.

Clearing the cache won't help, at least not in this place as it will never be called if there is sometihng in the cache!.

I moved statement for cache clearing into the calling method of refreshUsers before calling it, mappingDataRepository is not called anyway

And now I read cache before and it is NULL. So it is not called although cache is empty

Why are you even clearing the cache? Just call a method that has @CacheEvict with the name of the cache. I'm not even sure why you are trying to clear it yourself in the first place. You are trying very hard to work around the cache support for some reason.

I got help from a colleague and there was another class which disturbed this processing. Now all works. Thanks for trying to help!
